# Difference in run time complexity of two seemingly similar solutions

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I was trying to solve an assignment and wrote a solution that seems very close to the solution I found online when I set out to find more efficient solutions.

This is the assignment statement

> The goal of this problem is to implement a variant of the 2-SUM
>   algorithm covered in this week's lectures.
>
> The file contains 1 million integers, both positive and negative
>   (there might be some repetitions!).This is your array of integers,
>   with the ith row of the file specifying the ith entry of the array.
>
> Your task is to compute the number of target values t in the interval
>   [-10000,10000] (inclusive) such that there are distinct numbers x,y in
>   the input file that satisfy x+y=t
>   The variable `all_ints` is a list containing all the integers

```
hashtable = set(all_ints)
min_t = -1024
max_t = -min_t + 1

solutions = 0
k = 0

from time import time

# Solution 1 that I wrote
t0 = time()
for n in range(min_t, max_t):
    solutions+=1 if any([True if 2*i!=n and n-i in hashtable else False for i in hashtable]) else 0


# Solution 2 that I found online
t1 = time()
solutions2 = sum(1 for n in range(min_t, max_t) if any(n - x in hashtable and 2 * x != n for x in hashtable))
t2 = time()

print(t1-t0) #857.0168697834015
print(t2-t1) #591.8803908824921
```

Upon basic inspection, these two solutions look very similar. Yet, their run times are quite different and while both scale linearly, they deviate further away when I decrease the value of `min_t`.

[image]

What is the underlying difference between the two implementations that causing this

Comment: In solution 1 you are explicitly constructing a list of boolean results, whereas in solution 2 this is replaced with a simple generator expression.

Comment: As said above, you are doing `True if ... else False` explicitly. That's an additional step that, with larger values, can show some overhead. On top of that, you are building the whole list first and then checking whether any value in there is True. The second solution uses a generator, which is lazy, and as soon as it encounters a True value it will stop execution so it can save a lot of time.

Comment: @BramVanroy. Thanks, this helped. I removed the list and used a generator and shifted the if condition after the `for` to avoid explicitly calling `else`. That has shaved off quite a bit of time. You can post this as answer if you like and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above, you are doing True if ... else False explicitly. That's an additional step that, with larger values, can show some overhead. On top of that, you are building the whole list first and then checking whether any value in there is True. The second solution uses a generator, which is lazy, and as soon as it encounters a True value it will stop execution so it can save a lot of time.

The example below is your base code using 10K integers (instead of a million) for testing. Note that this way of timing is not very reliable (using `timeit` would be a better option) but for illustrative purposes, I guess it gives a good enough idea.

```py
import random
from time import time

all_ints = [random.randint(0, int(1E04)) for i in range(int(1E04))]
hashtable = set(all_ints)
min_t = -1024
max_t = -min_t + 1

solutions = 0
k = 0

# Solution 1 that I wrote
t0 = time()
for n in range(min_t, max_t):
    solutions += 1 if any(2*i!=n and n-i in hashtable for i in hashtable) else 0


# Solution 2 that I found online
t1 = time()
print('solution_1', t1-t0)

solutions2 = sum(1 for n in range(min_t, max_t) if any(n - x in hashtable and 2 * x != n for x in hashtable))
t2 = time()

assert solutions == solutions2

print('solution_2', t2-t1)
```

- solution_1 11.994043588638306
- solution_2 2.5971169471740723

Now, let's remove the list comprehension in favor of a generator:

```py
solutions += 1 if any(True if 2*i!=n and n-i in hashtable else False for i in hashtable) else 0
```

- solution_1 7.071138620376587
- solution_2 4.714937686920166

An additional improvement: you don't need the 'True if...', you can just pass in the condition itself:

```py
solutions += 1 if any(2*i!=n and n-i in hashtable for i in hashtable) else 0
```

- solution_1 6.017507076263428
- solution_2 2.9826767444610596

Finally: whenever you have a conditional consisting of multiple conditions, think very well about the order of the conditions. Order them from fastest to slowest. In your case, doing `2*i!=n` can be slower (especially for large values) than the set lookup (which is extremely fast), therefore I'd suggest swapping the order.

```py
solutions += 1 if any(n-i in hashtable and 2*i!=n for i in hashtable) else 0
```

- solution_1 3.184004545211792
- solution_2 2.4962565898895264

Now the only difference is that you have an explicit loop and (more importantly) that you do iterative addition instead of summing a whole list.

---

Here's a better benchmark (but the conclusions are the same):

```py
import timeit

setup = '''
import random
all_ints = [random.randint(0, int(1E03)) for i in range(int(1E03))]
hashtable = set(all_ints)
min_t = -1024
max_t = -min_t + 1
'''


# Solution 1 (original)
def sum_one(min_t, max_t, hashtable):
    solutions = 0
    for n in range(min_t, max_t):
        solutions += 1 if any([True if 2 * i != n and n - i in hashtable else False for i in hashtable]) else 0

    return solutions

# Solution 1 (generator instead of list comprehension)
def sum_one_gen(min_t, max_t, hashtable):
    """
    - generator instead of list comprehension
    """
    solutions = 0
    for n in range(min_t, max_t):
        solutions += 1 if any(True if 2 * i != n and n - i in hashtable else False for i in hashtable) else 0

    return solutions


def sum_one_gen_implicit_conditional(min_t, max_t, hashtable):
    """
    - generator instead of list comprehension
    - remove True if ... else False in favour of implicit conditional
    """
    solutions = 0
    for n in range(min_t, max_t):
        solutions += 1 if any(2 * i != n and n - i in hashtable for i in hashtable) else 0

    return solutions


def sum_one_gen_swap_conditions(min_t, max_t, hashtable):
    """
    - generator instead of list comprehension
    - remove True if ... else False in favour of implicit conditional
    - swap conditions
    """
    solutions = 0
    for n in range(min_t, max_t):
        solutions += 1 if any(n - i in hashtable and 2 * i != n for i in hashtable) else 0

    return solutions

def sum_two(min_t, max_t, hashtable):
    return sum(1 for n in range(min_t, max_t) if any(n - x in hashtable and 2 * x != n for x in hashtable))


sum_one_s = timeit.timeit(stmt='sum_one(min_t, max_t, hashtable)',
                          setup=setup + 'from __main__ import sum_one',
                          number=1000)
print('sum_one_s', sum_one_s)

sum_one_gen_s = timeit.timeit(stmt='sum_one_gen(min_t, max_t, hashtable)',
                              setup=setup + 'from __main__ import sum_one_gen',
                              number=1000)
print('sum_one_gen_s', sum_one_gen_s)

sum_one_gen_implicit_conditional_s = timeit.timeit(stmt='sum_one_gen_implicit_conditional(min_t, max_t, hashtable)',
                                                   setup=setup + 'from __main__ import sum_one_gen_implicit_conditional',
                                                   number=1000)
print('sum_one_gen_implicit_conditional_s', sum_one_gen_implicit_conditional_s)

sum_one_gen_swap_conditions_s = timeit.timeit(stmt='sum_one_gen_swap_conditions(min_t, max_t, hashtable)',
                                              setup=setup + 'from __main__ import sum_one_gen_swap_conditions',
                                              number=1000)
print('sum_one_gen_swap_conditions_s', sum_one_gen_swap_conditions_s)

sum_two_s = timeit.timeit(stmt='sum_two(min_t, max_t, hashtable)',
                          setup=setup + 'from __main__ import sum_two',
                          number=1000)
print('sum_two_s', sum_two_s)
```

Results:

- sum_one_s 144.5597518660361
- sum_one_gen_s 84.23750544409268
- sum_one_gen_implicit_conditional_s 78.40655627311207
- sum_one_gen_swap_conditions_s 57.4693741860101
- sum_two_s 52.64653824502602

Comment: There is a lot more to look at than I expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ClockSlave I've added a better benchmark script, but the conclusions are the same.

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that your extra list comprehension creation is slowing down your algorithm providing an extra container overhead.

The second solution uses a generator that yields values right away when it is computed, without needing a list.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question